# Spring Solr Geospatial Search

Tags: spring, solr, geospatial

I am trying to find some objects in a circle in solr by using their locations. This is the query that i want http://localhost:8983/solr/col/select?q=%3A&wt=json&indent=true&pt=10.34,12.4&d=5&sfield=location&fq={!geofilt}

but i cannot create the java code for this. I tried it like this

```
SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery();

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("location").near(new Point(10.34, 12.4), new Distance(5)));
SolrDocumentList docs = null;

try {
    QueryResponse rsp = server.query(query);
    docs = rsp.getResults();
} catch (SolrServerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But QueryResponse class do not allow this. What can i do can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem in my code, if anyone wants to know the new code, i put it here,

SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("location").within(new Point(lat, lon), new Distance(distance)));

```
    DefaultQueryParser qp = new DefaultQueryParser();
    final SolrQuery solrQuery = qp.constructSolrQuery(query);

    SolrDocumentList docs = null;
```

i add DefaultQueryParser and the problem solved.